# Match whole lines but remove specific word/expression directly from match

Tags: regex

I have a some multi-lines files that have strange format. It looks a little like this:

```
line 1: text1 0.2348953147573326nope text2Text3 text4\n
line 2: blabla-blabla\n
[...]
```

How can I match whole lines of data but remove those "0.2348953147573326" (random float values glued to some words) directly from the regex match? The expected regex match would be like:

```
text1 nope text2Text3 text4\n
blabla-blabla\n[...]
```

Comment: When you write `\n` are those newlines, or literal backslash-n?

Comment: @JohnKugelman \n means new line

Answer (score 0):

If the number you want to remove is always a decimal, this would do the job:

```js
let str = "text1 0.2348953147573326nope text2Text3 text4\n blabla-blabla\n[...]";
console.log(str.replace(/\d+\.\d+/, ""));
```

**Expression explained:**

- `\d+`: matches a digit (0-9) 1 or more times
- `\.`: matches a dot character (`.`)
- `\d`: as said before, matches a digit (0-9) 1 or more times

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out solution in terms of fit regex pattern. For me worked:

```
(^.+ (?=\d+\.\d+)|(?<=\d+\.\d+)\D.+$)|^((?!\d+\.\d+).)*$
```

- `(^.+ (?=\d+\.\d+)`: match stuff before excluded expression (in my example it is float value),
- `(?<=\d+\.\d+)\D.+$)`: match stuff after excluded expression,
- `^((?!\d+\.\d+).)*$`: match lines that doesn't contain excluded expression